# How to pass the properties of data to anotherViewController?(StoryBoard)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5

i want to pass the properties of data after select a tableviewcell.Please guide me.i already setup the detailviewcontroller.DataArray is my mutablearray in detailviewcontroller.peripheralManager is my NSbject.Peripheral is my device.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  peripheralManager=[[PeripheralManager alloc]init];
  self.MeBle.enabled=NO;
  device=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}
- (void)peripheralManagerDidConnectPeripheral:(PeripheralManager *)peripheral
{
  NSLog(@"%@",peripheral.deviceName);
  [device addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ",peripheral.deviceName]];    
   //   [device addObject:peripheral];
  [self.deviceTable reloadData];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier=@"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
  if(cell==nil)
{
    cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
   cell.textLabel.text=[device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //DetailViewController *detail=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
   // [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

   //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TableDetails" sender:[device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TableDetails"]) {

    DetailViewController *detail=segue.destinationViewController;
    detail.dataArray=device;


}
}
```

Comment: A view controller is an object, you pass data by calling methods on the object as you would in any other case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the prepareForSegue you should get the current selection index:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.deviceTable indexPathForCell:sender];
```

now, you may either pass just this index to the destination controller OR specific object from you current array, its up to you.

```
detail.idx = [indexPath row];
```

**Edit:** there you don't need to implement

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

just in

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

change to this:

```
detailViewObject.objCurrentDevice=[device objectAtIndex:[[self.deviceTable indexPathForCell:sender] row]];
```

Comment: no, idx is just NSInteger for the index of selected element. define the `@property(readwrite,assign) NSInteger idx` in your DetailViewController, and within in viewWillAppear you will have the current index to get.
however, I'd suggest not to pass entire array and index to the details controller, better pass just the active element. in this case you'd do something like this:
`NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.deviceTable indexPathForCell:sender];
detail.currentElem = [device objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];`

Comment: can u check for me @whiteagle

Comment: there you don't need to implement 
`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` , just in `- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` change to this: 

detailViewObject.objCurrentDevice=[device objectAtIndex:[[self.deviceTable indexPathForCell:sender] row]];

Comment: thanks for your time..:)..one more question friend how to pass NSMutableArray From NSObject Class to ViewController..please guide me

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, can you detail please ?

Answer (score 1):

In interface builder, check out the seague runtime attributes section, u can create multiple cell same style but different identifier then cellForRowAtIndexPath return the cell by its row